# Comment prononcer "51e"

Tags: prononciation, nombres

> Référendum: le Porto Rico se prononce pour devenir le **51e** Etat des Etats-Unis

Comment prononce-t-on "51e" ? Est-ce "cinquante-et-un-ième" ou "cinquante-et-une-ième" ou autre chose ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless of the gender of the word it applies to, *51<sup>e</sup>* is written *cinquante-et-[unième](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/uni%C3%A8me)* and that last component is never pronounced "*un - ième*" in French, i.e. *[œ̃ jɛm] or *[ɛ̃ jɛm].

There is no nasalisation so it is pronounced like "*une'ième*": **[ynjɛm]**

Comment: Comme dans  "Un bon signal" ou "Un bon avenir". "Bon" est prononcé différemment selon que le mot qui le suit commence par une voyelle ou par une consonne.

Answer (score 0):

*Cinquante-et-unième* because *État* is masculine and therefore *un* has to be  too.

Comment: We say _Cinquante-et-unième_ even with a feminine word: _La cinquante-et-unième réunion_

Comment: Yes of course, wasn't paying enough attention, lol.